# How to push a message loop in WinForms?

Tags: winforms, message-loop

In WPF, I can push a message loop using `Dispatcher.PushFrame`.

What is the equivalent in WinForms? I'm familiar with `DoEvents` but that must be called in a loop which can spin the CPU instead of the very efficient approach of just waiting for a message or for an event to signal to exit (like `Dispatcher.PushFrame` has).

Comment: There isn't one, ShowDialog() is as close as it gets.  I poked at alternatives for a while but the re-entrancy caused too many problems.

Comment: I've settled on `DoEvents` within a loop with a Sleep to keep the CPU from spinning to high.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to include `WindowsBase` to my project's references and just use `Dispatcher.PushFrame` and `frame.Continue = false` as usual.

Any caveats with wpf-winforms interop apply, and it does require part of wpf to be referenced, but it should still be better than `DoEvents` (which has severe pitfalls).

Answer (score -1):

This is the equivalent:

```
        System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback callback = o =>
        {
            this.Text = "Hello" + o.ToString(); // "Hello42"
        };
        WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current.Post(callback, 42);
```

The 42 is a `state` parameter that gets past to the callback.

You can also do this:

```
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.Text = "Hello"));
```

BTW, you should never ever ever use `DoEvents` - it's a great way to introduce bugs in to your code and is really only there for VB6 compatibility.

Comment: No, that's not the equivalent. That's just posting a message. My question is how to push a message loop that would process such a message.

I agree on `DoEvents` being exceptionally problematic and I avoid it like the plague. Nevertheless, for this unit test I'm writing, I don't need to worry about stray messages being processed and I do need to simulate the UI thread processing events since there in fact is *no* main message loop in my unit test.